# For JavaScript functions that create a DOM tree, what is the rationale behind passing a "container" node argument vs returning a root node

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I've noticed that JS libraries that create DOM trees almost always take a "container" node argument, under which they add their created DOM tree as a child (one example being `ReactDOM.render()`). It seems like another alternative would be for the function to just create a DOM tree (not yet added to the document) and return the root node of that tree. The caller could then add the tree to wherever it wanted in the document.

I suspect there must be some advantages to the container argument method, because it seems less elegant yet appears to be the widely accepted convention. Are there downsides to creating a DOM tree that isn't yet part of the document?

Comment: How would you create an element without having a reference to a document?

Comment: Yes, it is likely since the most common use case (especially with a name like `render`) is to add it into the DOM automatically. I think this scenario is changing (and likely should) as we get more into virtual DOM implementations.

Comment: @NineBerry Yes I should have mentioned that, it would be best to pass the document as an argument. Though it seems quite common in practice for code to assume a global `document` variable. My original question still stands though. Maybe it's just that if you're already needing to pass a document argument then people figure you might as well pass a specific container node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a new dom element is a function of an existing document. So, you at least need a reference to the document where you want to use the new element. When one would have to pass the document, then why not directly pass the desired parent element?